# Shopping cart promo code rules implementation

Tags: c#

An admin would create a promo code and choose from a list of predefined rules. The rules are constraints such as:

- Max uses
- Expire date
- Min cart subtotal
- etc

I could hard code these rules right into the code or I could (would like to) store the business logic in a database table and compile/execute it on the fly. Each business rule will be relatively simple and new ones could be created via the web admin. I imagine I could write some tests on creation of said rule to verify the code logic to some degree.

**Is storing the rule logic in a database a really bad idea?**

I think it's silly to hard code all of these rules and recompile each time a new one is added.

Note: I read that `System.CodeDom` would do the compiling on the fly for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, "store code written in C# as plain text" in the database, then compile it on the fly, then yes, it is a bad idea.  Having worked for several years on a project that stored code as data, I can tell you from experience that this is a decision you'll regret.

The most important reason it is a bad idea, is that turning code in to data means you can never change the interfaces/classes that this code might couple to.  This means that you better be able to predict and support every feature you might care about later right now, which is very hard.  This custom code can also be buggy, slow, and hard to debug.

**Update:**

There are other ways to solve this problem.  One way to look at this is to store `RuleSpecification` objects in the database, which might be as simple as a list of types and parameters for those types.  As far as configuring them in the web ui, I'd start with the ability to choose hardcoded contraints and be able to configure there parameters (set the data for the `ExpirationDataRule`, for example).  This will probably be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why not express the rules in a scripting language and have them interpreted when attempting to add the promo code?

**ELABORATION**

Instead of storing code that needs to be compiled (C# or otherwise), express your rules as javascript behind the scenes (you could use another scripting language, if you like, but javascript is ubiquitous). Then use a .NET javascript implementation (JScript or one of the open options available) to evaluate your javascript. So, your js might look like this:

```
promo.timesUsed < 5 && cart.total >= 35.00
```

Javascript bridges like JScript.Net and Java's Rhino generally provide the ability to take runtime objects and expose them to the scripting context. So in my example above, `promo` and `cart` would be C# objects that you expose to the scripting context. The only thing you have to honor now is what objects you'll expose to the scripting context. You would pass your script text to an eval method of some sort, and get a boolean back. You can create all sorts of rules, and you'll only be limited by the data available.